# How can I change the background-color using ng-class?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

I am trying to change the background color whenever someone inputs a '5' while using ng-class.  I am really new to AngularJS and just writing things to get the hang of it. Am I supposed to use an ng-if somewhere or have to change my CSS?  Also where would I have to input the code?  I know it has to be somewhere where I filter the number but am totally lost on how to write the code. Please help!

Here is my code:

```
<body ng-init="numbers=[0,1,2,3,4,5]">
<nav>
  <a href="#" ng-click="tab='numbers'" ng-class="{active:tab=='numbers'}">Numbers</a>
  <a href="#" ng-click="tab='form'" ng-class="{active:tab=='form'}">Form</a>
</nav>
<div ng-switch="tab">
  <div ng-switch-when="numbers">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myValue" />
    <h1 ng-repeat="number in numbers | filter:myValue"}>{{ number }}</h1>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="form">
    <button ng-click="numbers.pop(); tab='numbers'">Pop</button>
    <button ng-click="numbers.push(numbers.length); tab='numbers'">Push</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could easily use `ng-style` here

```
<input type="text" 
 ng-model="myValue" 
 ng-style="{'background-color':myValue == 5 ?  'red': 'white'}"/>
```

Using `ng-class` it would be

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myValue" ng-class="{'myOwnBg': myValue == 5}"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.myOwnBg {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the fast reply.
However, is there a way in using ng-class to do this?

Comment: NM my last comment, I guess the site didn't refresh fast enough before I typed my question. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @DavidTrinh Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Just the way you did with `ng-class="{active:tab=='numbers'}"`

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myValue" ng-class="{ bg : myValue == 5 }">
```

If you don't want to define a css class, you could use `ngStyle`.